# SystemVerilog: $urandom call inside conditional expression

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

So I wanted to set some bits in a vector with some hard-wired probability when an event was triggered, so I did this:

```
always @(some_event) begin
  err_byte[0] = ($urandom()&65535 < 85) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;  
  err_byte[1] = ($urandom()&65535 < 85) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;  
  //....etc
```

and my err_byte had always the value of 8'h00, even if this code was triggered several thousands of times (which should've been enough to set at least one bit to 1). When I declared an integer rndv and did this:

```
rndv = $urandom()&65535;
err_byte[0] = (rndv < 85) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
rndv = $urandom()&65535;
err_byte[1] = (rndv < 85) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
//etc...
```

then it suddenly works. Now the question: what the hell is happening here? Am I not allowed to call system tasks inside conditional expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator precedence.  `<` is ahead of `&` so your first example could be written like this.

```
err_byte[0] = ($urandom() & (65535 < 85)) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
```

See the problem now?